# Template not displaying using 'sub module'

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-routing

So I have my main module,

```
var panther = angular.module('panther', ['panther.sign_in']).config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false  
    })  
});
```

Which has a dependency of `panther.sign_in`,

```
angular.module('panther.sign_in', ['ngRoute']).config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/sign_in', {
        controller: 'controller_sign_in',
        templateUrl: 'assets/js/modules/core/sign_in/template.html'
    });
}]);
```

The controller looks like this,

```
angular.module('panther.sign_in').controller('controller_sign_in', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    alert('test');
}]);
```

The template looks like this,

```
<h1>Test</h1>
```

When I go to `/sign_in` it shows,

[image: 404]

My `index.html` file looks like this,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="panther">
<head>
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
<meta name="viewport"
    content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">

<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/base.css">

<title>Panther</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular-route.min.js"></script>

    <!-- CORE PANTHER FILES! -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/panther.js"></script>

    <!-- MODULE(S) INITIALISED HERE! -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/modules/core/sign_in/module.js"></script>

    <!-- MODULE(S) CONTROLLER(S) INITIALISED HERE! -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/modules/core/sign_in/controller.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Why does it not show the template file when I go to the URL `/sign_in`?

Secondly, is this the correct way to split a large application using Angular (using sub modules)?

**Edit #1**

In simple terms, I want it so that the user can type `http://www.mysite.online/sign_in` and the template/controller should show for that sub module. I've updated the main `panther` module as can be seen below:

```
var panther = angular.module('panther', ['panther.sign_in']).config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    /** Remove anything that has been appended to URL (#!). **/
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
});
```

I've changed my code to this, but it still didn't work.

Comment: Did you set up your server to redirect? Both need to be done when you choose html5mode

Comment: Nope, I have no idea what that means? If I remove `html5mode` would it work as I want it to?

Comment: See my answer below. I'm not sure your requirements, it may not be necessary.

Comment: @MathewBerg I simply want the route to work, whether it has `html5mode` or not is not a big deal, all I want as the end result is `http://mysite.online/sign_in` and template/controller should work, any ideas?

Comment: For the sake of sanity testing, can you move `$routeProvider.when('/sign_in', {...` block into the `panther` module and try hitting the route in the browser again?

Comment: @frishi After moving it to the `panther` module, it still shows the same error.

Comment: I started a fiddle to better understand your problem. http://jsfiddle.net/mtV62/1195/

Comment: @frishi looking at my code, can you see anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Fixed...

For those of you who like me are new to Angular, I forgot to add the `ng-view` hence the template could not be loaded. As a result nothing would work, all I did was had the following HTML and it worked.

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

**Reading Material**

[Modular AngularJS App Design](http://clintberry.com/2013/modular-angularjs-application-design/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to do server side url rewriting, see the docs on html5mode:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#server-side

Comment: See **Edit #1** or my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44934380/template-not-displaying-using-sub-module?noredirect=1#comment76844819_44934380).

Comment: I think @Script47 is simply trying to prove that client-side routing works and the link you posted explains methods to implement URL rewriting.

Comment: @frishi is correct, I would like to get the routing to work correctly.